# How to collect all data attributes and push to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of table rows with data attributes.  I would like to collect all the value of these data attributes and add them to an array.  How do I do this?

```
<tr data-title-id="3706" role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr data-title-id="3707" role="row" class="odd"></tr>
```

Comment: I would recommend a loop. How are you trying to do it right now?

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/44x46ygr/1/

Comment: Can you show your js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or the simplest method which will create the array and fill it in one step:

`var dataIds = $("table tbody tr").map(function() { return $(this).data('title-id'); });`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var data = [];
$('tr', yourTable).each(function() {
    data.push($(this).attr('data-title-id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful to get all data attrs to array of objects.

```js
var a = $('tr').map(function(x){
  return $(this).data();
}).toArray();
alert(JSON.stringify(a,null,'\t'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body><table>
<tr data-title-id="3706" data-title-val="Hello" role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr data-title-id="3707" role="row" class="odd"></tr>
</table></body>
```